# Weird getchar() output on file C program

Tags: c, file, getchar

So, I was tyring to write this code where an output txt file would copy everything the user typed, here is the code:

```
int main(){
FILE *txt = fopen("Output.txt","a");
char *Pcarac;
char carac;
Pcarac = &carac;

while(carac!='\n'){
    carac = getch();
    fprintf(txt,Pcarac);
}
return 0;
 }
```

However i always get these weird outputs ᝡ⋿਍７愢７ഢᜊ⋿ᝡ⋿ᝢ⋿ᝣ⋿ᝤ⋿ᜍ⋿ᝡ⋿ᝢ⋿ᝣ⋿ᜍ⋿ᜍ⋿.
Why is this happening and how can i solve it?
thanks

Comment: `fprintf( txt, "%c", carac )` or `fputc( carac, txt )`.  Using a single character where you should have a null terminated array of characters is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

try, `putc(char,FILE*)`

```
int main(){
FILE *txt = fopen("Output.txt","a");
char *Pcarac;
char carac;
Pcarac = &carac;

while(carac!='\n'){
    carac = getch();
    putc(*Pcarac, txt);
}
return 0;
 }
```